# Limits using intersection of closure of sets

Tags: calculus, limits

Today these two prepositions ocurred to me (I think intuitively they are true)

**Prop 1**. Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers.

We define $A_n = \{a_i, i \geq n \}$, and $L = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{A_n}$

(where $\overline{X}$ is the closure of the set $X$)

Then $L = \{x\} \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n} a_n = x$

**Prop 2**. Let $f : X \to Y$ be a function between two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$, and $x_0 \in \overline{X}$.

Let $r>0$, $B(x_0,r)$ be the open ball of center $x_0$ and radius $r$, let $A_r = f(B(x_0, r) \cap X)$, and let $L = \bigcap_{r > 0} \overline{A_r} $

Then $L = \{ y_0 \} \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = y_0$.

I still haven't tried to prove them.  Does anyone already know if they are true, or even if they already are in some book? Or if they are false and know a simple counter-example?

Thanks,
Damián.

Comment: No one did answer anything...